# mysql regular expression to replace all non alpha numeric characters

Tags: mysql, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Hi,

please help me in 
mysql regular expression to remove all non alpha numeric characters from a column data.

Thanks in advance.